# Cordova plugin not working after user agent changed

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I use ngcordova's [barcode scanner](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/barcodeScanner/) in an ionic project. On an iOS device, it works great. However, I needed to change the user agent. Using the following in `config.xml`:

```
   <preference name="OverrideUserAgent" value="something"/>
```

This snippet works fine on iOS. But for the platforms `browser` and `android` I receive an error that `cordova.js` is not defined. How is this possible?

## edit:

I suspect that the `cordova.js` not injected for the changed user agenet

## edit2

indeed there is some agent check in the plugin:

```
var aMat = sAgent.toString().match(/android ([0-9]\.[0-9])/i);
```

Comment: Each platform has its own cordova.js. Maybe cordova is checking the user agent?

Comment: I suspect that iOS ignoring the setting in the XML and thus, the iOS camera works. But the REST request fails ... See my last edit: do you know if cordova.js checks the user agent before it is injected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in edit 2 there is some pattern matching.

Thus choosing an user-agent like:

```
  <preference name="OverrideUserAgent" value="android1111111"/>
```

fixes the problem